# Return HTML from ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How to return HTML from ASP.NET MVC Web API controller?

I tried the code below but got compile error since Response.Write is not defined:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        Response.Write("<p>Test</p>");
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using WebAPI if you want to return HTML? I mean this is what ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebForms are for.

Comment: Thank you, excellent. I changed controller to regular controller.

Comment: @Stilgar One reason could have been that he does not use the MVC stack, neither any rendering engine but still want to provide a server facade to some Html. A use case can be that you have a Web Api that give some Html with a client side templating engine that will render everything in a later stage.

Comment: @Stilgar Another use case I encountered is returning an html page to provide feedback for an account creation confirmation, when the user clicks on the link you provide through email

Comment: Own use case: Provide styled / transformed XML document in HTML format
Could be XSLT 2.0  transforms which is not support on NET 7 but is on NET Framework 4.8

Answer (score 338, accepted):

### ASP.NET Core. Approach 1

If your Controller extends `ControllerBase` or `Controller` you can use `Content(...)` method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Index() 
{
    return base.Content("<div>Hello</div>", "text/html");
}
```

### ASP.NET Core. Approach 2

If you choose not to extend from `Controller` classes, you can create new `ContentResult`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Index() 
{
    return new ContentResult 
    {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        Content = "<div>Hello World</div>"
    };
}
```

### Legacy ASP.NET MVC Web API

Return string content with media type `text/html`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StringContent("<div>Hello World</div>");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Its not supporting in ASP.NET MVC Core HttpResponseMessage

Comment: @Parshuram I've just checked your statement. I can use HttpResponseMessage in ASP.NET Core. It is located under System.Net.Http.

Comment: ohk thanks but now MediaTypeHeaderValue not supporting

Comment: When I do this using ASP.NET MVC 5 I get the response. I don't get any of the HTML content back. All I receive is  "StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: text/html
}"

Comment: @guyfromfargo have you tried `[Produces]` approach?

Comment: for me the code above works perfect on my local iis express but in normal iis it throws an exception that can serialize the response Type 'System.Net.Http.StringContent' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Answer (score 65):

Starting with AspNetCore 2.0, it's recommended to use `ContentResult` instead of the `Produce` attribute in this case. See: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6657#issuecomment-322586885

> This doesn't rely on serialization nor on content negotiation.

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Index() {
    return new ContentResult {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"
    };
}
```

Comment: I could not get the "produces" answer to work at all on 2.0, this however works fine.

Comment: If you want to show a html from file, just add "var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("index.html");"

Comment: Yup, if you are using ASP.NET Core 2.0 this is the way to go!

Comment: What if the HTML file is in the local directory and it also has css, js linked. How do we serve the file then?

Comment: For Razor Pages, you can call the PageModel Content() method instead of creating ContentResult directly. I'm not sure if this is available for Controllers as well.