# How to pass HTML formatted email body to a javascript function using asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, outlook

Here is the C# part

```c#
for (int i = 0; i <= mailergrd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    SBEmailBody.Append("<'html><'body><table><tr><td>  Dear  <b> <name>,    </td></tr></table></b>  <br/><br/>  Welcome  <br/>" + "hiii.<br/>"+</body></html>");

    SBEmailBody.Replace("<name>", mailergrd.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),     "SendMail"+i, "SendMail('TO@syn.com','" + SBEmailBody.ToString() + "','Greetings     from PDAC','CC@syn.com');", true);
}
```

Here is the JavaScript part

```js
function SendMail(to,body,sub,cc)
{
    var theApp;  
    var theMailItem;  
    var subject = sub;
    var msg = body;
    var carbon = cc;

try
{
    var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");        
    var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0);
    theMailItem.To = to;
    theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
    theMailItem.CC = carbon;
    theMailItem.Body = (msg); 
    theMailItem.Display();
 }
```

OUTPUT

```html
<html><body><table><tr><td>  JOHN <b> ,</td></tr></table></b> <br/><br/> Welcome <br/>" + "hiii.<br/>" +</body></html>
```

I'm trying to send E-Mails from client-side which is working fine except for the body of the mail: its not html formatted while passing from code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the HTML formatted string to theMailItem.HTMLBody property, not .Body.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Many Questions Like these have Been Answered Before.

[Return HTML from ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822277/return-html-from-asp-net-web-api)
Have a look at that and See if its a possible Solution.

Comment: Thank you Retic for your response but  HttpResponseMessage property is asking for a class to create and more over im not using MVC, could you please help me more on this..!