# Server side rendering. Web API and Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-universal

I've developed a web application built  using `ASP.NET Core Web API` and `Angular 4`. My module bundler is `Web Pack 2`.

**I would like to make my application crawlable or link sharable by Facebook, Twitter, Google. The `url` must be the same  when some user tries to post my news at Facebook. For example, Jon wants to share a page with url - `http://myappl.com/#/hellopage` at Facebook, then Jon inserts this link into Facebook: `http://myappl.com/#/hellopage`.**

I've seen this tutorial of [Angular Universal server side rendering without tag helper](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/607) and would like to make server side rendering. As I use `ASP.NET Core Web API` and my `Angular 4` application does not have any `.cshtml` views, so I cannot send data from controller to view through `ViewData["SpaHtml"]` from my controller:

```
ViewData["SpaHtml"] = prerenderResult.Html;
```

In addition, I see [this google tutorial of Angular Universal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtoHFDfi8FM&feature=youtu.be&t=9m49s), but they use `NodeJS` server, not `ASP.NET Core`.

I would like to use server side prerendering. I am adding metatags through this way:

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
    private metaService: Meta) {
}

let newText = "Foo data. This is test data!:)";
    //metatags to publish this page at social nets
    this.metaService.addTags([
        // Open Graph data
        { property: 'og:title', content: newText },
        { property: 'og:description', content: newText },        { 
        { property: "og:url", content: window.location.href },        
        { property: 'og:image', content: "http://www.freeimageslive.co.uk/files
                                /images004/Italy_Venice_Canal_Grande.jpg" }]);
```

and when I inspect this element in a browser it looks like this:

```
<head>    
    <meta property="og:title" content="Foo data. This is test data!:)">    
    <meta property="og:description" content="Foo data. This is test data!:)">
    <meta name="og:url" content="http://foourl.com">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.freeimageslive.co.uk/files
/images004/Italy_Venice_Canal_Grande.jpg"">    
</head>
```

I am bootstrapping the application usual way:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and my `webpack.config.js` config looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');

var ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

var isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');

function getPlugins() {
    var plugins = [];

    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, you can now use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; UglifyJS will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }
    }));

    plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    }));
    plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin(
        [
            './wwwroot/js',
            './wwwroot/fonts',
            './wwwroot/assets'
        ]
    ));

    return plugins;
}


module.exports = {

    devtool: 'source-map',

    entry: {
        app: './persons-app/main.ts' // 
    },

    output: {
        path: "./wwwroot/",
        filename: 'js/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.js',
        publicPath: "/"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal',
        outputPath: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'tslint-loader',
                enforce: 'pre'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',

                    'angular-router-loader',

                    'source-map-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "file?name=img/[name].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,                
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    },
    plugins: getPlugins()

};
```

Is it possible to do server side rendering without `ViewData`? Is there an alternative way to make server side rendering in ASP.NET Core Web API and Angular 2?

I have uploaded [an example to a github repository](https://github.com/NiceStepUp/PrerendererJustAngular).

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices yet?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov yeah, it is necessary to use `ViewData` to send html to `.cshtml` view in this tutorial, but I am using just `.html` views, not `.cshtml` views.

Comment: Alright, why do you think you need cshtml view? Why not simply return `prerenderResult.Html` from action?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov I've read this: `For example, open Views/Home/Index.cshtml, and add markup like the following:` and this `Now go to your Views/_ViewImports.cshtml file, and add the following line:

@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices"` here: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#server-side-prerendering

Comment: in the bold part, you say "The url must be the same", but then, example urld differ. Did you mean `http://myappl.com/#/hello` instead of `http://myappl.com/#/hellopage`?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl you are right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option in Angular to use HTML5 style urls (without hashes): [LocationStrategy and browser URL styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles). You should opt this URL style. And for each URL that you want to be shared o Facebook you need to render the entire page as shown in the tutorial you referenced. Having full URL on server you are able to render corresponding view and return HTML.

Code provided by @DávidMolnár might work very well for the purpose, but I haven't tried yet.

**UPDATE:**

First of all, to make server prerendering work you should not use `useHash: true` which prevents sending route information to the server.

In the demo [ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 universal app](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal) that was mentioned in GitHub issue you referenced, ASP.NET Core MVC Controller and View are used only to server prerendered HTML from Angular in a more convenient way. For the remaining part of application only WebAPI is used from .NET Core world everything else is Angular and related web technologies.

It is convenient to use Razor view, but if you are strictly against it you can hardcode HTML into controller action directly:

```
[Produces("text/html")]
public async Task<string> Index()
{
    var nodeServices = Request.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<INodeServices>();
    var hostEnv = Request.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

    var applicationBasePath = hostEnv.ContentRootPath;
    var requestFeature = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
    var unencodedPathAndQuery = requestFeature.RawTarget;
    var unencodedAbsoluteUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{unencodedPathAndQuery}";

    TransferData transferData = new TransferData();
    transferData.request = AbstractHttpContextRequestInfo(Request);
    transferData.thisCameFromDotNET = "Hi Angular it's asp.net :)";

    var prerenderResult = await Prerenderer.RenderToString(
        "/",
        nodeServices,
        new JavaScriptModuleExport(applicationBasePath + "/Client/dist/main-server"),
        unencodedAbsoluteUrl,
        unencodedPathAndQuery,
        transferData,
        30000,
        Request.PathBase.ToString()
    );

    string html = prerenderResult.Html; // our <app> from Angular
    var title = prerenderResult.Globals["title"]; // set our <title> from Angular
    var styles = prerenderResult.Globals["styles"]; // put styles in the correct place
    var meta = prerenderResult.Globals["meta"]; // set our <meta> SEO tags
    var links = prerenderResult.Globals["links"]; // set our <link rel="canonical"> etc SEO tags

    return $@"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href=""/"" />
<title>{title}</title>

<meta charset=""utf-8"" />
<meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"" />
{meta}
{links}

<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css"" />

{styles}

</head>
<body>
{html}

<!-- remove if you're not going to use SignalR -->
<script src=""https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js""
        integrity=""sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=""
        crossorigin=""anonymous""></script>

<script src=""http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.0.min.js""></script>

<script src=""/dist/main-browser.js""></script>
</body>
</html>";   
}
```

Please note that the fallback URL is used to process all routes in `HomeController` and render corresponding angular route:

```
builder.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
      name: "spa-fallback",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

To make it easier to start consider to take that demo project and modify it to fit with your application.

**UPDATE 2:**

If you don't need to use anything from ASP.NET MVC like Razor with NodeServices it feels more natural to me to host Universal Angular app with server prerendering on Node.js server. And host ASP.NET Web Api independently so that Angular UI can access API on different server. I think it is quite common approach to host static files (and utilize server prerendering in case) independently fro API.

Here is a starter repo of Universal Angular hosted on Node.js: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.

And here is an example of how UI and web API can be hosted on different servers: https://github.com/thinktecture/nodejs-aspnetcore-webapi. Notice how API URL is configured in `urlService.ts`.

Also you could consider to hide both UI and API server behind reverse proxy so that both can be accessed through same public domain and host and you don't have to deal with CORS to make it work in a browser.

Comment: @StepUp, I have updated my answer, I home it makes more sense now.

Comment: In my view, there is no difference between your answer and Dávid Molnár.

Comment: @StepUp, fair enough. Anyway, you asked for an example of server-side rendering an there is an example. In what way does not it work for you?

Comment: cause I have many html pages to be posted and  if I use this way it would be really bad to render each page in a such way.

Comment: @StepUp, why do you need to prerender it from ASP.NET Core? You can setup nodejs server that will server prerendered HTML and access APIs exposed by ASP.NET Core WebAPI. Won't it be easier? If not then I believe it is possible to run invoke nodeService https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices directly to handle the request and return rendered HTML from ASP.NET Core. Seems to cause more overhead though. How do you think?

Comment: How can I do it? I mean nodejs which can prerender HTML and access API?

Comment: @StepUp, here is angular universal starter https://github.com/angular/universal-starter. Which uses node to prerender. It can access web api same was a browser does - make real http requests. But requests will be done in same network or even on same server and will be fast enough. So node and web api will be two different apps that run in different processes.

Comment: but how can I work them(NodeJ and ASP.NET Core) together using my configuration?

Comment: @StepUp, it is hard to tell exactly because I don't see your application, but I would consider to make angular UI hosted by nodejs one independent application (the serves html, js, css, does server prerendering) and ASP.NET Core Web API - another independent application (that only exposes http api). It will make hosting and deployment a bit more complex, but will ensure clear separation of concerns.

Comment: Could you show some tutorials where it can be seen how it is possible to deploy independent `Angular 2` application by nodejs and another independent `ASP.NET Core WebAPI` application that work together?

Comment: @StepUp, I have found repo https://github.com/thinktecture/nodejs-aspnetcore-webapi that shows how same API can be build with both nodejs and webapi and consumed by angular ui. In `urlService.ts` you simply specify what url you want to use to access API. So again it two independent servers will we deployed - one to serve html, js, css, etc with node and one - asp.net web api. You can host both behind reverse proxy so that you don't need to configure CORS.

Comment: Feel free to make a reply of your recommendations about distinct deployment with a reference to a github and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @StepUp, great, I have updated my answer. Hope it helps finding the approach that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your linked tutorials you could return the HTML directly from the controller.

The prerendered page will be available at `http://<host>`:

```
[Route("")]
public class PrerenderController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("text/html")]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var requestFeature = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
        var unencodedPathAndQuery = requestFeature.RawTarget;
        var unencodedAbsoluteUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{unencodedPathAndQuery}";
        var prerenderResult = await Prerenderer.RenderToString(
            hostEnv.ContentRootPath,
            nodeServices,
            new JavaScriptModuleExport("ClientApp/dist/main-server"),
            unencodedAbsoluteUrl,
            unencodedPathAndQuery,
            /* custom data parameter */ null,
            /* timeout milliseconds */ 15 * 1000,
            Request.PathBase.ToString()
        );
        return @"<html>..." + prerenderResult.Html + @"</html>";
    }
}
```

Note the `Produces` attribute, which allows to return HTML content. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26822588/1093508) question.

Comment: How can I direct to use this url by SEO? For example, a browser address of my page is `http://myappl.com/#/hello`, but SEO should seeks another address(`http://myappl.com/api/prerenderer`)?

Comment: @StepUp, sounds like your question does not reflect what you want. Try explain better what you want to achieve. There is not way to make it work with hashes in URL because browser don't sent part of url after `#` to server. All server will get from `http://myappl.com/#/hello` is `http://myappl.com/`.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov  What I want is **to make my application to be crawlable or link sharable by Facebook, Twitter, Google.** To do it, I am using metatags `constructor( private metaService: Meta) {}` in `mypage.component.ts`, however the page is not crawlable and sharable by Facebook. Twitter or other social nets.

Comment: Now I understand what you want. You'll need to dynamically create the HTML page for `http://myappl.com`. You are now serving the HTML file generated by Webpack/Angular. It's a static HTML file. You need to return a dynamic HTML file with the contents of the `prerenderResult.Html` + your HTML. Normally you would do this in a `.cshtml` file. But you do not have one.... As a dirty workaround you could concatenate the `<html>...` with the `prerenderResult.Html`, but that's not really nice.

Comment: it is not eligible for me. I cannot change url of the page. The `url` must be the same  when some user tries to post my news at Facebook. For example, Jon wants to share a page with url - `http://myappl.com/#/hellopage` at Facebook, then Jon inserts this link into Facebook: `http://myappl.com/#/hello`.

Comment: @StepUp, I don't see how it will be possible to achieve if you cannot change URL and Facebook cannot run scripts. Would be nice to see a good answer. I will also try to investigate a bit more on my spare time.