# Asp.Net MVC - Failed to start monitoring file changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to write my own CMS using ASP.NET MVC and I store html views in DB. I created custom virtual path provider by tutorial in the internet.

**MyVirtualPathProvider Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using SgCms.Dal.Concrete;
using SgCms.DomainModels;

namespace SgCms.ViewFactory
{
    public class SgCmsVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            var view = GetViewFromDatabase(virtualPath);

            if (view == null)
            {
                return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
        {
            var view = GetViewFromDatabase(virtualPath);

            if (view == null)
            {
                return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.
                    GetBytes(view.InnerHtml);
                return new SgCmsVirtualFile
                    (virtualPath, content);
            }
        }

        private View GetViewFromDatabase(string virtualPath)
        {
            return PageBuilder(virtualPath);
        }

        private View PageBuilder(string path)
        {
            var virtualPath = path.Replace("~", "");

            DataContext db = new DataContext();
            var view = from v in db.Views
                where v.Path == virtualPath
                select v;

            var res = view.SingleOrDefault();

            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyVirtualFile Code:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace SgCms.ViewFactory
{
    public class SgCmsVirtualFile : VirtualFile
    {
        private byte[] viewContent;

        public SgCmsVirtualFile(string virtualPath,
            byte[] viewContent) : base(virtualPath)
        {
            this.viewContent = viewContent;
        }

        public override Stream Open()
        {
            return new MemoryStream(viewContent);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get views from DB by path like that: http://localhost/Module_Name/View_Name

I wrote my custom route and now all requests handle by one action.
Even, when GetViewFromDatabase is called it get view which I want. 
But, unfortunately I have next exception:

> Directory 'c:\users\nikita litvinenko\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SgCms\SgCms.Web\Views\Main' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Directory 'c:\users\nikita litvinenko\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SgCms\SgCms.Web\Views\Main' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below
>   Stack Trace: 
>       [HttpException (0x80070002): Directory 'c:\users\nikita litvinenko\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SgCms\SgCms.Web\Views\Main' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.]
>          System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.FindDirectoryMonitor(String dir, Boolean addIfNotFound, Boolean throwOnError) +589
>          System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.StartMonitoringPath(String alias, FileChangeEventHandler callback, FileAttributesData& fad) +655
>          System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency.Init(Boolean isPublic, String[] filenamesArg, String[] cachekeysArg, CacheDependency dependency, DateTime utcStart) +2582
>          System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheDependency(String virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart) +400
>          System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider.GetCacheDependency(String virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart) +36
>          System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider.GetCacheDependency(VirtualPath virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart) +38
>          System.Web.Compilation.MemoryBuildResultCache.CacheBuildResult(String cacheKey, BuildResult result, Int64 hashCode, DateTime utcStart) +68
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CacheBuildResultInternal(String cacheKey, BuildResult result, Int64 hashCode, DateTime utcStart) +70
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +10180802
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +294
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath) +15
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +6
>          System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765901
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Well you need to override GetCacheDependency method in your SgCmsVirtualPathProvider as well - probably with something backed up by db timestamp.

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you, so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty easy. As said [Ondrej Svejdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2440262/ondrej-svejdar) I just should override GetCacheDependency method in my SgCmsVirtualPathProvider.

```
    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(
        string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        var view = GetViewFromDatabase(virtualPath);

        if (view != null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath,
            virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't, instead of work with files, return the response in a stream?

[wath this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822277/return-html-from-asp-net-web-api)