# Return HTML from ASP.NET Web API ASP.NET Core 2 and get http status 406

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is a follow-up on [Return HTML from ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822277/return-html-from-asp-net-web-api).

I followed the instructions but I get Error 406 in the browser.
My code:

```
    [Produces("text/html")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AboutController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "<html><body>Welcome</body></html>"; 
        }
...
```

and, simply:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

When I remove the `Produces` line I get the plain text `<html><body>Welcome</body></html>` in the browser (no error).

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Details about why your are getting a 406 response here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4846

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As [KTCO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882912/ktco) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822277/return-html-from-asp-net-web-api) :

> Starting with ***AspNetCore 2.0***, it's recommended to use `ContentResult`
>   instead of the `Produce` attribute

The solution is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Get()
{
    return new ContentResult {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = "<html><body>Welcome</body></html>"
    };
}
```

There is no need to change `AddMvc` (and there is no `Produce` attribute, of course).

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: With NetCore v3.1 you can also use the int constants class StatusCodes (using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;), so that, we may use: 
`StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Content-Type` header to `text/html` in the request which you are sending while using `Produces` attribute.

If you are sending through browser then it will work good because browser by default sends `Content-type` header as `text/html`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean: first the browser is sending the request so I have no control over this; second according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting "web browsers tend to supply Accept headers that include a wide array of formats, including wildcards. By default, when the framework detects that the request is coming from a browser, it will ignore the Accept header and instead return the content in the application's configured format (JSON unless otherwise configured)".

Comment: Thanks - I saw your edit. However that is exactly my question: it should work but it does not work for me. Why ? I though my question was clear about that since I did specify browser: "... followed the instructions but I get Error 406 in the `browser`".

Comment: Can you verify from developer tools of the browser that the content-type send by the browser for the request is text/html

Comment: Good idea. I tried 4 browsers and Postman but did not specifically checked the request Content-Type header. I will and get back here soon.

Comment: @FrankMonroe Did it helped?

Comment: Sorry, been busy. The browser sends `Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*`
I think the issue is with the `AddMvc` code; I need to add a serializer for HTML. I don't really know.