# Why getting 406 Not Acceptable in ASP.NET Core 2.1.3 web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, http-status-code-406

My action method:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("text/xml")]
    public async Task<GetJobsForThirdPartyResponse> GetJobs(GetJobsForThirdPartyQuery query)        
    {            
        var response = await this.Bus.Query(query);
        return response.Data;
    }
```

My partial `Startup` class:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });
```

Postman request is like bellow:
[image]

[image]

I've also tried `[Produces("application/xml")]` with `Accept: application/xml` header request. But no luck.

Comment: Can you try with json. or default output to ensure this issue with xml

Comment: Yes it produces json successfully. Problem is with XML.

Comment: you are writing XML or JSON at the body? if you specify XML to be the format then set the body to be XML too; did you try that?

Comment: Yes I've done that by selecting `Body` tab then by selecting `XML` option in postman. Even I've removed the parameter from action method like `GetJobs()`. Still no hope.

Comment: I was also facing similar problem but the answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822277/return-html-from-asp-net-web-api helped me a lot.