# Extracting Content from HttpResponseMessage as HTML not string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, httpresponsemessage

There are a number of similar questions regarding extracting the content of an HttpResponseMessage, but most are looking for JSON or text.

I have an API in c# that calls another API which returns a Razor page. When I call the second API from Postman, it returns nicely formatted HTML that could be displayed in a browser right away. All I want my API to do (in this instance) is act as a middleman between the browser and the second API.

```
            var client = new HttpClient();

            const string uri = "Second API";

            var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                // Data being sent to second API.
                {"path", "/somehwere/somefile.extension"}
            };
            var encodedFormData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
            
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, encodedFormData);
```

Now I have the response. If I do the following:

```
var test = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The result is a string with various formatting characters such as "/n". This is not valid HTML and cannot be set as the src of an IFrame in the client browser (which is ultimately what I want to do).

I don't have an issue returning the data that I have extracted to the initial caller, my issue is with formatting.

How do I return valid HTML when I know that the second API is returning it (because Postman displays the html nicely, and because the browser can make the request and display it properly)?

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` header of the response?

Comment: @NoahStahl The response that my API recieves from the second api is "text/html". This would as well be why the response is able to be displayed in a browser and in postman. This is also why I think the issue is with how I am accessing the content. Clearly "ReadAsStringAsync()" isn't doing the trick.

Comment: there's some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822277/return-html-from-asp-net-web-api  So just create a page that is served up in the iframe have that controller return the HTML.

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks, but the answers on that page all presume I have valid HTML like "<p>something</p>". That's my problem, I effectively just want to play the middleman and re-route the valid HTML returned from the second API to the caller, but in being the middleman I ruin the HTML. Accessing it as a string results in invalid HTML with formatting characters like "/n".

Comment: maybe Ajax is the answer here... just return/append HTML datatype to the iframe?  (jQuery's $.get or $.post will parse header from content...)

Comment: It may be worth using Fiddler to look at the raw response before it hits your code, just to make sure it's proper HTML encoded in the way you expect.